# Adding a delay to one javascript slideshow so each plays differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, slideshow, delay

I have two query slide shows on the same page and they play simultaneously. I want to add a delay to one of the slide shows so that they do not change at the same time. For example I want slideshow1 to have a delay of 1000ms at the beginning so slideshow2 changes first. I've tried to add the delay function to the jquery file with my slideshows, but it doesn't work. Could you check out my code below and let me know if you have any ideas? Thanks a million!

http://pastebin.com/aaGFLD26

Comment: Did you change the value in switchTime:3000,              duration:650,

Comment: yes, but I would like them to both initialize at the same time, just one should wait a few seconds and then continue at the same switching pace as the other so these two values should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a delay at the init.
launch the first one, wait DELAY, launch the second

[EDIT]

```
 jQuery('div.slideshow').fadeGallery({
            ...
 });

jQuery('div.slideshow2').delay(DURATION).fadeGallery({
```

Comment: I don't think I can use the php function usleep in javascript. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: Forgive me im a bit ignorant with javascript. how would i implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout to delay the second gallery.

```
jQuery('div.slideshow').fadeGallery();

setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('div.slideshow2').fadeGallery();
}, DELAY_VALUE);
```

Comment: Hmm, I couldn't get this working - ideally I would like both to appear at the same time, I just don't want one to start rotating after a delay then assume the same rotation period as the other. Any ideas?